# Why does v1 web component customElements.define() throw TypeError

Tags: javascript, web-component

I'm playing around with v1 web components. According to Eric Bidelman in [Custom elements v1: reusable web components](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/customelements/), a v1 web component can be defined and created with:

```
class App extends HTMLElement {

  attachedCallback() {
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.innterHTML = `<div>web component</div>`

  }
}
```

and

```
<x-app></x-app>
```

However, when running the code in the latest version of Chrome Canary and with the v1 polyfill in Firefox, the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
```

Comment: ES5 consideration for custom elements: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/423

Answer (score 4):

If you transpile your es6 code you'll need to include the native-shim.js code from webcomponents/src/CustomElements/vs.

Comment: Hey there.. how does this work for older browsers? It seems you're not supposed to transpile the native-shim.js to ES5 so I'm not sure how this works with, say, iOS 8 that doesn't natively support ES6 or custom elements.