# Transpiling class based web components with babel

Tags: javascript, babeljs, web-component, custom-element

I've a simple web component following the latest [web components v1 class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements), it works great in Chrome and Firefox/Edge (with a polyfill) but I'd like it to run in IE11 so I need to transpile the class. However running it through babel produces code that no longer works in any browser.

Is there any way to generate backwardly compatible web components with the class syntax or is there a preferred way to write web components for maximum compatibility?

Example code -

```
class TestElement extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback(){
    this.innerHTML = "<div>Testing</div>"
  }
}

customElements.define('test-element', TestElement)
```

Error message when using transpiled code is -

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003413/babeljs-doesnt-transpile-extended-classes-properly which is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832646/extending-built-in-natives-in-es6-with-babel - if it is, then next time try searching for transpile OR babel extends

Comment: That sounds like the underlying problem, I'm interested in how people work around this in relation to web components - or can the two not work together?

Comment: Workaround? http://stackoverflow.com/a/39376819/295783

Comment: Thanks but after running with this transpiled code gives "TypeError: Illegal constructor"

Comment: I have never transpiled, I just tried to find you examples. I also did not hammer close as duplicate for the same reason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To compile Custom Element classes with Babel, you can use this [plugin](https://github.com/github/babel-plugin-transform-custom-element-classes) from Github.

It will use `Reflect.construct()` instead of `new`, which is not permitted with `HTMLElement` objects.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use the native-shim available with this polyfill
https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements

It's not perfect though, would like to find a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks, seems this is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477678/why-does-v1-web-component-customelements-define-throw-typeerror

Comment: works perfectly - after having had many trouble with other solutions. btw they say "We are also working on some future refinements to this approach that will improve the implementation and automatically detect if it's needed.". interestingly firefox does not need the shim.